# How to create double structure arc diagram using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I want to create arc diagram with arc connecting on both sides of x-axis using d3.v4.I have tried with arc connecting on the top side. Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it ?
[image]

Comment: Can you share an image that better describes what you want to achieve? Are you looking for a [sunburst](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst)?

Comment: No.I am looking for Arc Diagram.

Comment: https://d3-graph-gallery.com/arc